# Matching user input with indexOf

Tags: javascript, input, indexof

I'm trying to display text that matches user input. It displays the result when user enter first character e.g 'a' but nothing happens when second character is entered e.g 'as'. So I want Baseball and Fast to be displayed when user enters as.

```
// JavaScript Document

s1= new String()
s2= new String()
var myArray = new Array();

myArray[0] = "Football";
myArray[1] = "Baseball";
myArray[2] = "Cricket";
myArray[3] = "Fast";


function test() //  called onkeyup() event
{
 s1 = document.getElementById('filter').value;
 s2 = s2+s1;
 arraysearch();
}

function arraysearch()
{
    for(i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
    { 
       if (myArray[i].indexOf(s2) != -1) // also tried using match method
       { 
           alert('Matched');           
           document.getElementById('placeholder').innerHTML += myArray[i] + "<br/>";
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: you must use 'onchange' event or 'keyup' event to get characters as they are entered.

Comment: You are doing a case-sensitive match. You should consider converting the strings to lower-case when comparing them. Or else, typing "football" won't match the item "Football" (with a capital F).

Comment: I haven't included the html file but the test() function is being called on onkeyup() event. Also user input is 'as' so it should return Fast and Baseball in any case.

Comment: You're using `s2=s2+s1`, so in `as`'s case, I guess your `s2` would be `aas`, and no match is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried this out, and i implemented a solution to help you. You can use regex to better compare and match strings. It uses jquery just for dom manipulation, but thats about it. You can go ahead and edit it. Hope it helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/cy4QH/2/

Comment: Ok so the initial issue is fixed. But what do I use instead of append in javascript. Currently, the code does not remove the previous result from display. E.g if I type 'as', I get the following result:
Football
Baseball
Fast
Baseball
Fast

The first 3 appear when I typed a and the last 2 appear when I typed as. I want the first 4 to disappear when I type s after a.

Comment: Check this out, update, no jquery methods, just native javascript. http://jsfiddle.net/cy4QH/6/

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function ShowMe(obj) {

                var lbl = document.getElementById('divContent');

                var myArray = new Array();
                myArray[0] = "Football";
                myArray[1] = "Baseball";
                myArray[2] = "Cricket";
                myArray[3] = "Fast";

                var s2 = obj.value.toLowerCase();

                for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                    if (myArray[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(s2) != -1) 
                    {
                        lbl.innerHTML = myArray[i];
                    }
                }

            }

        </script>
```

HTML Code

```
<div>
<h1>JS Test</h1>
    <input id="txtInput" onkeyup="javascript:ShowMe(this)" />
    <div id="divContent">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If "filter" is a input element and you set its "onKeyUp='javascript:arraysearch()'", this code should work for you.

```
function arraysearch() 
{ 
  for(var i in myArray) 
  {  
    if (myArray[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(document.getElementById('filter').value) != -1) 
    {  
       alert('Matched');            
       document.getElementById('placeholder').innerHTML += myArray[i] + "<br/>"; 
    } 
  } 
}
```